# Drawing trainrail-bends using DrawArc (C# OOP)

Tags: c#, oop, graphics

I am trying to build a Windows Forms Application where i can draw a rectangle with a trainrail-bend in it. Like the following example:

[image: bend example]

I used object orientated programming to write the classes using a class-diagram.

```
 class SpoorRailsKrom : SpoorElement
{
    protected RailsRotatie rotatie;
    public SpoorRailsKrom(Orientatie orientatie, int breedte, int grootte, int x, int y) : base(orientatie, breedte, grootte, x, y)
    {
    }
    public override void Teken(Graphics g)
    {
        if (g != null)
        {
            //TODO: Draw Rails using rotatie (angle)
            base.Teken(g);

            g.DrawArc(Pens.Black, 5, 5, 100, 100, 0, 90);
            g.DrawArc(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 100, 100, 0, 90);

        }
    }
}
```

In the "Teken"-method i want to draw the bends with the different rotations (0 to 90, 90 to 180, 180 to 270 and 270 to 360 (0)) using an enumeration (rotatie).

```
namespace EindopdrachtOOP_Spoorbaan

enum RailsRotatie
{
    _0,
    _90,
    _180,
    _270
}
```

I also wrote a class SpoorElement to draw the rectangle where the bend has to be drawn in.

```
 abstract class SpoorElement
{
    protected int breedte, grootte, x, y;
    protected Orientatie orientatie;

    public Orientatie Orientatie
    {
        set
        {
            orientatie = value;

        }
        get
        {
            return orientatie;
        }
    }

    public SpoorElement(Orientatie orientatie, int breedte, int grootte, int x, int y)
    {
        this.orientatie = Orientatie.Horizontaal;
        this.breedte = 100;
        this.grootte = 100;
        this.x = 5;
        this.y = 5;
    }

    public virtual void Teken(Graphics g)
    {
        if (g != null)
        {
            //Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, breedte, grootte);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: bend]

My question is:

How can i change the angle that it will draw the bend like the example (the first image)?

Comment: Use g.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points); with up to 360 points

Comment: You need to calculate the correct rectangle(s) and better understand the start angle. The rectangle will never be the ones you use for drawing the tiles, btw!

Comment: ..Or use graphics transformation rotation and translation.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying my question, I tried using transformation rotation but it didnt work, can you give me an example?

Comment: g.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points); doesn't work, it only gives me 1 line.